# how to float divs in a <li> but still stack the <li> entries vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` where each `<li>` will have 2 divs.  I would like the divs to float next to one another, but still have the `<li>`s stack vertically.  My problem is that all my divs are floating instead of each `<li>` going beneath the previous.  What style changes to i need to make here?

Thanks!
[image]

```
// Add the message to the page. 
$('#conversation').append('<li><div class="chat-container"><div class="' + cssStyle + '"></div><div class="chat-text"><strong>' + encodedName + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</div><div></li>');
```

My Styles:

```
#conversation >li > div > div {
    float: left;
}
.legend {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.chat-text {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

with the answer i now get this as i wanted.

[image]

Comment: Are you floating just to shrink the elements?

Comment: no i was floating because i didn't want to make a table, maybe i should have just made the table.  I'm programmatically setting this div's class value (<div class="' + cssStyle + '"></div>) to sprite value for the avatar image, i didn't want the message text to over lap so i wanted to float the text next to the sprite image div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your having a clearfix problem.

Add this to your style, but you will most likely need to make this a CSS class so it doesn't apply to all `li` tags:

```
li{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/6J8SU/

To add the class change your script:

```
$('#conversation').append('<li class="row"><div class="chat-container"><div class="' + cssStyle + '"></div><div class="chat-text"><strong>'
            + encodedName + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</div><div></li>');
```

Then add this styling:

```
.row{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Example with Class** http://jsfiddle.net/6J8SU/1/